# Rewriting a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(\Delta^\varepsilon)^n a_n$ in the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \varepsilon^n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I would like to rewrite the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(\Delta^\varepsilon)^n a_n,$$ where $\Delta^\varepsilon=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \varepsilon^k b_k$, as a series in $\varepsilon$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \varepsilon^n$$ (i.e., I need to find the $c_n$).

Obviously, I can do this term-by-term.  But the general case seems quite difficult.

Comment: You can use Cauchy products for $\Delta^{\varepsilon}$, viewed as a power series. 

Comment: You want the composition of formal power series. You can find it everywhere. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Composition_of_series

Comment: Oh...I just noticed the comment by Pietro Majer.  Thank you.  That is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have, using Cauchy products, at least for $\varepsilon$ small enough, that 
$$(\Delta^{\varepsilon})^n=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\sum_{j_1+\dots+j_n=k}\prod_{i=1}^nb_{j_i}\right)\varepsilon^k,$$
hence, if the coefficients have a good behaviour
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n!}(\Delta^{\varepsilon})^na_n&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n!}a_n\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\sum_{j_1+\dots+j_n=k}\prod_{i=1}^nb_{j_i}\right)\varepsilon^k\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n!}a_n\left(\sum_{j_1+\dots+j_n=k}\prod_{i=1}^nb_{j_i}\right)\varepsilon^k.\\\
\end{align}
So we can take 
$$c_k:=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n!}a_n\left(\sum_{j_1+\dots+j_n=k}\prod_{i=1}^nb_{j_i}\right)$$
for $k\geq 1$ and $c_0=0$.

Comment: Davide, This is incredibly helpful to me! If it is okay with you, I would like to add an acknowledgement of your help in my paper. I can also send you a draft the paper before I submit it if you like.

Comment: No problem. What is your paper about?

Comment: I study financial mathematics.  The paper is about deriving the implied volatility smile for exponential Levy models...not sure if that makes any sense to somebody that doesn't study financial math.